# Delete an row or put sentinel data

Tags: matlab

I'm running a sorting algorithm.

I have a matrix of integers, and I know that the all integers in it are less than 1000.
Is it better to delete a row (using `x(10,:) = []`) or just put an invalid value, say 1001, in every slot in the row?

I'm thinking about efficiency here.

Comment: Why does your sorting algorithm involve deleting things?

Comment: Joing Oli to this question. But if, for any reason whatsoever, you want to delete values during sorting, I recommend not resizing matrices in MATLAB. Just mark the row as invalid by putting an illegal value in the first element of the row, such as 1001 or, even better, NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the sake of comparison, just run tic/toc.

```
X = randn(1000);
time1 = 0;
for i= 1:100
    X = randn(1000);
    tic
    X(10,:) = [];
    a = toc;
    time1 = time1 +a;
end
time2 = 0;
for i= 1:100
    X = randn(1000);
    tic
    X(10,:) = 1001;
    a = toc;
    time2 = time2 +a;
end

disp ([time1 time2])
0.3882    0.0026
```

verdict: insert value. I'm guessing because deleting a row may have something to do with rearranging the matrix. just make sure that when sorting, your algorithms only touches the "illegal values" once, otherwise you need to do some complicated big O computations to solve your problem